# Lubuntu 16.04 I can't ping my router via WiFi, but can do it with Ethernet

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, ping

I have Lubuntu 16.04. I can ping whatever via Ethernet.
WiFi **does** obtain IP, but I can't ping 192.168.10.1 which is the same router as for Ethernet

```
sudo rout -n:

0.0.0.0  192.168.10.1  0.0.0.0  UG  100  0 0  enp1s0

0.0.0.0  192.168.10.1  0.0.0.0  UG  600  0 0  wlp2s0

192.168.10.0  0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0  U  100  0 0  enp1s0

192.168.10.0  0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0  U  600  0 0  wlp2s0
```

The only difference is the Metric. Could that be a problem?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
lspci -nn:

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Memory Controller Hub [8086:27ac] (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27ae] (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a6] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 [8086:27d0] (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 [8086:27d4] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27b9] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:27c4] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
```

Edit2:

```
sudo traceroute 192.168.10.1
```

Wifi:

```
traceroute to 192.160.10.1 (192.160.10.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
```

Ethernet:

```
traceroute to 192.160.10.1 (192.160.10.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  TEW-692GR (192.168.10.1)  0.512 ms  0.464 ms  0.541 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  1.629 ms  1.615 ms  1.572 ms
 3  207.194.53.193 (207.194.53.193)  5.541 ms  15.114 ms  25.270 ms
 4  154.11.12.203 (154.11.12.203)  5.544 ms  5.856 ms 154.11.12.201 (154.11.12.201)  5.755 ms
 5  sea-b2-link.telia.net (213.248.74.220)  5.732 ms  5.738 ms  6.089 ms
 6  ntt-ic-337606-sea-b2.c.telia.net (213.248.70.13)  6.672 ms  5.554 ms  5.453 ms
 7  ae-1.r22.sttlwa01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.9)  5.750 ms  5.610 ms  5.518 ms
 8  ae-0.r24.nycmny01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.4.14)  72.760 ms  71.798 ms  72.423 ms
 9  ae-9.r24.londen12.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.19)  137.700 ms  137.156 ms  137.354 ms
10  ae-8.r02.londen03.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.4.22)  136.852 ms  136.615 ms  137.611 ms
11  c4l-0.r02.londen03.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (83.231.146.230)  138.738 ms  138.436 ms  137.059 ms
12  et-1-0-0.vansen.the.uk.v4.as25577.net (84.45.27.147)  137.599 ms  137.517 ms  137.361 ms
13  et-2-2-0.lucia.sov.uk.v4.as25577.net (84.45.27.155)  137.114 ms  136.021 ms  137.287 ms
14  et-1-0-0.beorn.hex89.uk.v4.as25577.net (84.45.27.156)  135.483 ms  135.511 ms  133.391 ms
15  beorn-hex89-ringo.c4l.co.uk (84.45.21.187)  132.457 ms  132.432 ms  133.032 ms
16  81.27.83.158 (81.27.83.158)  139.514 ms  137.341 ms  136.002 ms
17  81.27.90.100 (81.27.90.100)  135.491 ms  135.295 ms  135.223 ms
18  81.27.90.97 (81.27.90.97)  138.150 ms  139.239 ms  137.892 ms
19  81.27.90.100 (81.27.90.100)  137.161 ms  137.614 ms  136.426 ms
20  81.27.90.97 (81.27.90.97)  138.654 ms  139.300 ms  139.855 ms
21  81.27.90.100 (81.27.90.100)  137.306 ms  137.367 ms  137.680 ms
22  81.27.90.97 (81.27.90.97)  140.444 ms  141.550 ms  138.811 ms
23  81.27.90.100 (81.27.90.100)  137.198 ms  138.644 ms  137.150 ms
24  81.27.90.97 (81.27.90.97)  140.149 ms  138.873 ms  138.735 ms
25  81.27.90.100 (81.27.90.100)  136.942 ms  136.756 ms  136.668 ms
26  81.27.90.97 (81.27.90.97)  138.631 ms  141.104 ms  141.257 ms
27  81.27.90.100 (81.27.90.100)  138.437 ms  138.397 ms  138.099 ms
28  81.27.90.97 (81.27.90.97)  139.111 ms  139.233 ms  141.176 ms
29  81.27.90.100 (81.27.90.100)  136.011 ms  137.161 ms  138.707 ms
30  81.27.90.97 (81.27.90.97)  140.606 ms  140.413 ms  140.553 ms
```

ip addr show dev enp1s0

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:08:06:f3:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.127/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 604304sec preferred_lft 604304sec
    inet6 fe80::129d:d8bc:692a:c8dc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip addr show dev wlp2s0

```
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:db:df:2b:b6:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.121/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 598095sec preferred_lft 598095sec
    inet6 fe80::2db:dfff:fe2b:b6a0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

EDIT3:
lspci -nnk

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN [8086:5201]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Which PCI ID and kernel module? See `lspci -nnk`.

Comment: Updated above. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe router prevents ping from wifi. Check in router admin if there is such option enabled.

Comment: I can ping router from my main laptop via WiFi no problem. From Lubuntu, via WiFi I can't ping nothing and cannot do even appt-get install

Comment: I included the `k` so we could get info on kernel modules. You can trim out everything except the last bit, which is the "Network controller."

Comment: Updated with latest edit.

Comment: I also just searched for additional drivers in SW updates. It found none.

Comment: can you try disabling bluetooth?

Comment: I did {sudo systemctl disable bluetooth --now}. With or without reboot, doesn't work.